# CSS margin-bottom property not working

Tags: html, css

I defined this CSS class and apply it to a line of text, and want it to be placed at the very bottom of the page, but it doesn't. It floats in the middle of the page. What's wrong with ?

```
#bottom {        
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="bottom">
     <a href="/bword/index.jsf;jsessionid=fc87GyPawnkaIWb_y6ig9Zsmo9aa9wbaizVNFAE7.localhost">Privacy policy</a>    
</div>
```

Comment: it's defined in an external CSS file.

Comment: That's fine, but CSS is meaningless by itself.  It only takes on meaning in the context of an HTML file that is being rendered.  Your question cannot be answered without seeing the HTML you are trying to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `#bottom` to remain at the bottom of the **page**, then

http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/1068/

CSS:

```
#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

or if you need at the bottom of the **viewport/screen**, then:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/1069/

**CSS**

```
    #bottom {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#bottom {
     bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    text-align: left; 
}
```

this will solve your problem

Comment: This indeed works, except that I changed to "text-align:center". Why do I need " left:0 " and "right:0 "?

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you want to do is to stick a text to the bottom of the page.
So the CSS should look like

```
#bottom { position:fixed; bottom: 0px; }
```

But without a more detailed description, I cannot know, if this is what you want to do.

Margin is not the property to use for. Maybe have a look into the description here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp